# In the given figure each unit square is colored red or green randomly. Find the probability that none of the four 2x2 squares is monochromatic

Tags: probability

[image]

There are 4 possible 2x2 squares in the figure. The total ways of coloring squares is $2^9$ obviously.
But I have no idea how to select non monochromatic squares (here non monochromatic means none the 2x2 should be made of different color and not a color)

Can I get a hint?

Comment: 1. Count ways of coloring when one definite 2x2 square is monochromatic.
2. Count ways of coloring when two definite 2x2 squares are monochromatic.
3. Count ways of coloring when three definite 2x2 squares are monochromatic.
4. Count ways of coloring when all four 2x2 squares are monochromatic.
5. Use inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Are you aware of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Answer (score 2):

One nice approach is to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

---

### Notation

Label each of the 4 $2 \times 2$ squares $1,2,3,4$. In particular:
$$
1: \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\times &\times& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\times&\times&\phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\phantom{\times}&\phantom{\times}& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\end{array}, \quad 
2: \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\phantom{\times} &\times& \times\\
\hline
\phantom{\times} &\times&\times\\
\hline
\phantom{\times}&\phantom{\times}& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\end{array}, \\
3: \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\phantom{\times}&\phantom{\times}& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\phantom{\times} &\times& \times\\
\hline
\phantom{\times} &\times&\times\\
\hline
\end{array}, \quad 
4: \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\phantom{\times}&\phantom{\times}& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\times &\times& \phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\times&\times&\phantom{\times}\\
\hline
\end{array}.
$$

Let $A$ denote the set of all colorings. For $i = 1,2,3,4,$ let $A_i \subset A$ denote the set of colorings for which square $i$ is monochromatic. Let $|S|$ denote the number of elements in the set $S$.

---

### Particular counts

I claim that $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 2$; if all size 2 squares are monochromatic, then either all squares are red or all are green.

I claim that $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 4$; if three squares are monochromatic, then the coloring has the form
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
R&R&R\\
\hline
R&R&R\\
\hline
R&R&R/G \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
possibly with the colors flipped.

I claim that $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 2^4$. Each coloring in $A_1 \cap A_2$ has the form
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
R&R&R\\
\hline
R&R&R\\
\hline
R/G & R/G & R/G \\
\hline
\end{array},
$$
possibly with the colors flipped.

I claim that $|A_1 \cap A_3| = 2^3$. Each such coloring has the form
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
R&R&R/G\\
\hline
R&R&R\\
\hline
R/G & R & R \\
\hline
\end{array},
$$
possibly with the colors flipped.

Finally, $|A_1| = 2^6$. Each such coloring has the form
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
R&R&R/G\\
\hline
R&R&R/G\\
\hline
R/G & R/G & R/G \\
\hline
\end{array},
$$
possibly with the colors flipped.

---

### Result

The inclusion-exclusion principle gives us the formula

$$
\begin{align}
\left|A \setminus \left[ \bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i \right]\right| &= \sum_{J \subset [4]} (-1)^{|J|} \left| \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j\right|
\\ & = 
|A| - \sum_{i=1}^4 |A_i| + (|A_1 \cap A_2| + |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_4|) 
\\ & \quad + (|A_1 \cap A_3| + |A_2 \cap A_4|)
- \sum_{i=1}^4 \left|\bigcap_{j \in [4]\setminus\{i\}} A_j\right|
+ |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\\ & = 
2^9 - 4 \cdot 2^6 + 4 \cdot 2^4 + 2 \cdot 2^3 - 4 \cdot 4 + 2
\\ & = 
2^9 - 2^8 + 2^6 + 2^4 - 2^4 + 2 = 322
\end{align}
$$
That is, $322$ colorings yield no monochromatic $2 \times 2$ squares. That means that the probability of such a coloring is
$$
\frac{322}{2^9} = \frac{161}{256} \approx 0.629.
$$